# Responsive Headers with Elm-UI

Tags: elm

I am using elm-ui.  The header feature is amazing, but does not seem to be responsive by default.  I don't see anything about responsive design in the documents.  Is there a way to implement this feature within the elm-ui ecosystem, or do you need to integrate it into bootstrap or something responsive?

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of digging around the elm-ui github repo, it looks like indeed there is no answer for the responsive bit. And in general, elm really doesn't have an answer for responsiveness (Excluding elm-style-elements). I'd reccomend using media queries.

Check out [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/) article to get started.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit frustrating.  A better question, then, is what is the best way to implement responsveness in Elm...can you select different `Html Msg` functions depending on whether the client is desktop or mobile (without some crazy port-based system)

Comment: I'd use Elm Style Elements personally, it doesn't give you so much out of the box as elm-ui does, but it is a great experience nonetheless, and the layout \ responsiveness couldn't be easier, check it out here
http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/style-elements/4.3.0/Element#Device

Comment: Elm UI 2 is coming brewing a good solution for responsive and more ... stay tuned !!